# Build project with Appveyor and two toolsets MSVS and MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, rapidjson, appveyor

There is a nice project RapidJson. It uses Appveyor CI to test builds for Windows and MSVC 2015. I am going to add build config for MinGW. But I cannot find a way how to do that.

Please consider [`appveyor.yml`](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/appveyor.yml) from official repository:

```
os: Visual Studio 2015 CTP  
version: 1.1.0.{build}

configuration:
- Debug
- Release

environment:
  matrix:
  # - VS_VERSION: 9 2008
  #   VS_PLATFORM: win32
  # - VS_VERSION: 9 2008
  #   VS_PLATFORM: x64
  - VS_VERSION: 10 2010
    VS_PLATFORM: win32
  - VS_VERSION: 10 2010
    VS_PLATFORM: x64
  - VS_VERSION: 11 2012
    VS_PLATFORM: win32
  - VS_VERSION: 11 2012
    VS_PLATFORM: x64
  - VS_VERSION: 12 2013
    VS_PLATFORM: win32
  - VS_VERSION: 12 2013
    VS_PLATFORM: x64
  - VS_VERSION: 14 2015
    VS_PLATFORM: win32
  - VS_VERSION: 14 2015
    VS_PLATFORM: x64

before_build:
- git submodule update --init --recursive
- cmake -H. -BBuild/VS -G "Visual Studio %VS_VERSION%" -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=%VS_PLATFORM% -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=true -Wno-dev

build:
  project: Build\VS\RapidJSON.sln
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal

test_script:
- cd Build\VS && if %CONFIGURATION%==Debug (ctest --verbose -E perftest --build-config %CONFIGURATION%) else (ctest --verbose --build-config %CONFIGURATION%)
```

I know I need add

```
environment:
  matrix:
  - PROFILE: MINGWx64
    PLATFORM: x64
```

Then on before_build step generate `cmake -BBuild/MinGW -G"MinGW Makefile" ...`.
And on build step `cmake --build`
test_script will look like similar, but I don't understand how should I write different build steps for different platforms.
Please help. Thanks in advance.